# C#: What happens if I try to lock a locked object?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

for example--

```
Object obj = new Object();
```

then I lock one section with `lock(obj)`

and I lock in other section also `lock(obj)`

if one thread is in the first section, does that mean that the other section is also locked?

Answer (score 2):

Locking is done on an object, not on a section or location of the code. If one thread takes the lock in the first location, the second thread can't take it anywhere - neither in the same location and nor in any other location.

Comment: So if let's say I write in other location: while(true) { lock(obj) ....} for the other  thread will try to take the lock until the first thread will unlock? Is that like wait/pulse?

Comment: You don't need and shouldn't use a while loop